# What's so special about Indexhibit?

Tags: web, content-management-system, portfolio, indexhibit

It seems that Indexhibit (www.indexhibit.org) is a sort of standard when it comes to building portfolio websites for artists. I just received a mail from an artist asking me whether I use Indexhibit. Beside the issues of the customer poking their nose into technical stuff, I need to know what's so special about Indexhibit?

I took a look at it and saw nothing more then a somewhat original CMS. I have my own system/libraries that I use to build simple websites and prefer sticking to these, but would like to know first... why does Indexhibit have this place among artists... and why do they say "an Indexhibit site" and not "a website built on Indexhibit"... what's the difference between an Indexhibit website and a plain website? Is there any advantage when using Indexhibit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's it, you got it, it's just a blank slate that makes it easy to pump out a small portfolio in a short amount of time.  It's the helvetica of portfolio web design.  Nothing fancy, but it's classic, the art can breath.

Answer (score 1):

I come from a ASP.NET MVC and Django Background, and I've actually been having a bit of fun about working with Indexhibit. I got over my fear of PHP and there is some thing refreshing about just firing a query off, and building html straight out of it. Would never use it for a really custom job, but for things that fit the model, it gets quite out of your way for getting things done.

Comment: I've got to check it out for myself... thanks!